# Retrieve last row from the Google DataStore Java

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to retrieve the last row from the data store so how can i do that??
I know the long method i.e

```
 for(Table_name e: resultset)
     {
            cnt++;
     }
  results.get(cnt).getvalue();
```

I have String with (number) as primary key.can i use it to get descending order???

Is there any method through which i can get the last row???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably sort in the opposite order (if possible for your query, the data store has some restrictions here) and get the first result of that.

Also, if you store numbers in String fields the order may not be what you want it to be (you might need padding here).

Comment: What do you mean by padding??? I didnt understand the meaning of padding?? Can u elaborate on this??

Comment: Strings sort like `1, 10, 11, 100, 2`. With padding `001, 002, 010, 011, 100`.

Comment: ...why would you store numbers in string fields in the first place?